# Retrying active job, Unsupported argument type: Time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
class SendTrackerToShipupJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default
  retry_on StandardError, wait: 5.seconds, attempts: 3

  def perform(tracker)
    response = Shipup.new().sendTracker(tracker)
    if response.code != 201
      puts response.code, response.message
      raise "Couldn\'t send tracker to Shipup"
      return
    end
    shipment = Shipment.find_by(tracking_code: tracker[:tracking_number])
    shipment.sent_to_shipup = true
    shipment.save
  end
end
```

I intentionally make the job fail to check if it triggers again 3 times every 5 seconds.

```
SendTrackerToShipupJob.set(wait: 5.minutes).perform_later(...)
```

But here is my output log :

3:59:21 PM web.1    |  Retrying SendTrackerToShipupJob in 3 seconds, due to a StandardError. The original exception was nil.
3:59:21 PM web.1    |  Unsupported argument type: Time

And it won't triggers again. Any ideas?

Comment: how are you executing this job ?, are you doing a perform now ?. If so, it could be possible that the`tracker` object your passing, contains some Time attributes that can't be serialized and that could be causing the issue. Not sure really if that could be the case, because if I'm not wrong, active job calls `to_json` on the object to serialize it :/

Comment: Oh I completely forgot the method call, I edited my question @fanta

Comment: Oh my you were right, it comes from a date into `tracker`

Comment: cool, it'd be good if you post your fix so that someone can find an answer if facing something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because you are parsing a date into the JSON object you pass as the job argument.

In my example:

```
SendTrackerToShipupJob.set(wait: 5.minutes).perform_later({
    [...]
    created_at: ...
})
```

The created_at attribute causes the problem.
In order to fix this, transform your JSON into a hash:

```
SendTrackerToShipupJob.set(wait: 5.minutes).perform_later({
    [...]
    :created_at => ...
})
```